# My question how to ask for forgiveness against other person ,but only i know of the sin

Tags: allah, sin, dua, forgiveness, tawba

If my sin involves a person but they were not harmed, I should still ask for their forgiveness. Only I know the sin I committed against them; they are unaware of it. I'm very worried if I can't ask for forgiveness. Also, I know if I do have to ask for forgiveness, do I have to tell the reason, or could I just say, "I did something bad, please forgive me"?